# How to calculate $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{2 -\cos(x) - \cos(y)}{x^2+y^2}\;?$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

How to calculate $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{2 - \cos(x) - \cos(y)}{x^2+y^2} = \dfrac12\;?$

I was thinking, if breaking numerator into:

$$\big(1 - \cos(x)\big) + \big(1 - \cos(y)\big) = 2\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) + 2\sin^2\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)$$

and then using this identity would help, but cannot proceed further.

I would appreciate any hints.

Thanks.

Comment: $1-\cos x\neq 2\sin (\frac x 2)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm yes, thanks, should be $\sin^2$

Comment: Use: $\cos x=1-\frac {x^{2}} 2+o(x^{3})$.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good. I am not sure what happens if I divide $o(x^{3})$ by $(x^2 + y^2)$ and similarly with $o(y^{3})$. If it will be $0$, then it will be fine.

Comment: put $y=kx$, And use $\frac{sinx}{x}=1$ for x tending to $0$

Comment: Yes, it's fine. Thanks. Any term of $o(x^3)$ can be written as $Kx^n$ , where K is some constant. For any $n \ge 3$: $x^n = x^{n-2}  \frac{x^2}{x^2 + y^2} \le x^{n-2}  \frac{x^2 + y^2}{x^2 + y^2} \le x^{n-2} \rightarrow 0$, for $(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)$

Comment: Correction: For any $n \ge 3: \frac{x^n}{x^2 + y^2} = x^{n-2}\frac{x^2}{x^2 + y^2} \le ...$. Also similarly for $o(y^3)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\;\lim\limits_{t\to0}\dfrac{1-\cos t}{t^2}=\dfrac12\;,\;\;0\leqslant\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\leqslant1\;,\;0\leqslant\dfrac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}\leqslant1$

and

$\dfrac{2-\cos x-\cos y}{x^2+y^2}=\left(\dfrac{1-\cos x}{x^2}-\dfrac12\right)\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}+\left(\dfrac{1-\cos y}{y^2}-\dfrac12\right)\dfrac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}+\dfrac12\;\;,$

it follows that

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{2-\cos x-\cos y}{x^2+y^2}=\dfrac12\;.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Using polar coordinates gives
\begin{align*}
\frac{1-\cos(x)-\cos(y)}{x^2+y^2}&=\frac{2-\cos(r\cos(\theta ))-\cos(r\sin(\theta ))}{r^2}\\
&=\frac{1-\cos(r\cos(\theta ))}{r^2}+\frac{1-\cos(r\sin(\theta ))}{r^2}.
\end{align*}

Check what happen for $\theta \in \{0,\frac{\pi}{2},\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2}\}=:S$ and when $\theta $ doesn't belong to to $S$, and conclude.